# error serving react app using react-app-wired

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid, react-app-rewired

I have a react application created with **create-react-app** using **react-data-grid@7**. Since canary17 they started to use **es2020 modules**, to using the more recent builds I have to add support to **optional-chaining** and **nullish-coalescing-operator** to the app, otherwise I have errors starting the app.
After a few searchs, I installed **customize-cra** and **react-app-rewired**, changed the scripts commands to

```
"start": "react-app-rewired start"     
"build": "react-app-rewired build"
```

and added this **config-overrides.js**

```
const {
    override,
    addBabelPlugin
 } = require("customize-cra");

 module.exports = override(
    addBabelPlugin("@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"),
    addBabelPlugin("@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"),
 );
```

Trying to run the app I obtain a strange behavior.
using the **start** command I obtaing the same error, but if I build and the deploy the app works correctly.
If I add something wrong in the config-overrides.js and try to start run start I received an error message, so I think the file is loaded.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests I found the solution changing from

```
addBabelPlugin("@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"),
addBabelPlugin("@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"),
```

to

```
addExternalBabelPlugin(["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining", { "loose": false }]),
addExternalBabelPlugin(["@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator", { "loose": false }]),
```

I added the loose parameter too, but it was not the problem. now looks like works both in serve and build